# Cross-entropy vs dot product

Tags: classification, cross-entropy

Performance of classification algorithms is quantified by comparing the predicted probability distribution of the labels $q$ to the true probability $p$, which is commonly a vector of zeros for all labels except the true label, where it is 1. The [cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) is given by
$$L(p, q) = -\sum_i p_i \log q_i$$

My question is whether the logarithm operation is necessary. It would seem to me that a simple dot product between the two unit vectors $p$ and $q$ would achieve more or less the same result

$$L_2(p, q) = 1 - \sum_i p_i q_i$$

This loss would be exactly zero when $p = q$ and would reach at most 1 when $p$ and $q$ are very different.

What are the advantages of using cross-entropy over dot product? I do agree that it has some fancy information-theoretic interpretation, but if its effect in ML happens to be the same as that of a dot product, perhaps one can accelerate the whole procedure by not computing logarithms?

Comment: The cross-entropy operation arises when you are trying to perform maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters of a multinominal distribution. The information theory perspective is just a by-product.

Comment: @mhdadk ah, that makes sense. Still, would be interesting to see whether minimizing CE leads to a better estimator than maximizing dot product in case of finite data.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins how do you define "better"?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins what you are essentially asking for is a better estimator than the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE). This could be hard to come by, since the MLE has some nice properties, such as consistency.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins For instance, to be “better”, do you mean better out-of-sample predictions? // The dot product is related to the cosine of the angle between two vectors. Isn’t cosine similarity a popular performance metric in these kinds of problems?

Comment: @Tim That's what I'd like to know too. I mean, it's possible for an estimator to be better in many ways, such as better bias-variance tradeoff, numeric stability etc.

Comment: @Dave Yes, out of sample predictions are a good way to be better. No, I have not heard of the dot product used in classification problems before, but that may simply mean my lack of awareness rather than anything else

Comment: @mhdadk Note that the loss function is not strictly an estimator, the estimator is the probability that minimizes it. If the problem is unconstrained, both loss functions produce the same estimator, as they have the same minimum. Their difference is in the shape of the slopes.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins not sure what you mean. The maximum likelihood estimator returns the parameters that maximize the likelihood function given a sample.

Comment: @mhdadk The point I am trying to make is that there are multiple different loss functions, minimising which (in theory) would result in the same set of parameters as minimizing the likelihood function. In this case, the dot product is one such function. However, there are more subtle differences between loss functions, e.g. how well would a gradient descent converge over them.